# How to disable magnify glass that appears with a touch and hold on mobile Safari?

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile, safari, mobile-safari

How to disable magnify glass that appears with a touch and hold on mobile Safari?

I cannot prevent the event(ontouchstart) from happening with javascript because I need scrolling functionality in the area where I want to disable the magnifier.

I have read that the following should work but it does not.
[preventing magnifier to appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332750/preventing-magnifier-to-appear)
[Disable the text-highlighting magnifier on touch-hold on Mobile Safari / Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923782/disable-the-text-highlighting-magnifier-on-touch-hold-on-mobile-safari-webkit)

```
:not(input) {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;    
}
```

I'm also trying to avoid using a JavaScript scrolling library and just disable the event with JavaScript.

Any help will be very appreciated.