# Iphone on long press causing some rectangular magnifier to pop up

Tags: ios, css, iphone, angularjs, cordova

Each time I long press on any view/screen there is some kind of rectangular magnifier which pops up. See image for more information[click to view rectangular magnifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra9qR.jpg)

It appears in a specific area each time no matter where i press and hold on the screen. I would like to disable the rectangular magnifier, i have tried the following codes in css:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none; 
-webkit-user-select: none; 
-khtml-user-select: none; 
-moz-user-select: none; 
-ms-user-select: none; 
-o-user-select: none; 
user-select: none;
```

But it does not get disabled. Here is a [video](http://recordit.co/g879oCFvpS) so you can have more information about the issue:

Comment: Isn't this part of the system.  Normally used to make sure you are clicking the area that you intend to click?  Something like, "these objects are pretty close, which one do you want".

Comment: Or it is the copy/paste widget. Have you had you iPhone long? Do you use it often?

Comment: @durbnpoisn No it appears in a specific area each time no matter where i press and hold on the screen. I would like to disable the rectangular magnifier, i have tried the following codes in css:
`code`
    -webkit-touch-callout:  none;
    -webkit-user-select:    none;
    -khtml-user-select:     none;
    -moz-user-select:       none;
    -ms-user-select:        none;
    -o-user-select:         none;
    user-select:            none;
`code`
But it does not get disabled. Here is a video so you can have more information about the issue: http://recordit.co/g879oCFvpS

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 No i am creating a phonegap/cordova app and this keeps appearing whenever i press and hold on the application screen. 

happens only when i disabled copy/paste option

see this video: http://recordit.co/g879oCFvpS

Comment: I don't know what say. I'm too tired.

Comment: If this is indeed a phonegap thing, then I think I'm right.  Because that is a function that is used in web views to magnify the screen when it's not sure which element you intended to click on.

Comment: @durbnpoisn thanks for your reply. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: My only suggestion would be to keep your elements further apart and larger.

Answer (score -1):

@jessemonroy650
There is only js/jquery way:
    document.addEventListener("touchstart",
    function(e) {
    this.trigger("click");
    e.returnValue = false 
    });

more info on
[Disable the text-highlighting magnifier on touch-hold on Mobile Safari / Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923782/disable-the-text-highlighting-magnifier-on-touch-hold-on-mobile-safari-webkit/40131401#40131401)